# Form validation after dirty/touched (onblur)

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

`ng-zorro-antd` forms work fine with the angular form validation, however, it displays validation messages such as with `nzErrorTip` as soon as the user begins typing. I would like this validation to display after the user leaves (blurs) the input field for the first time.

Is this possible to hook into `nzErrorTip`/etc or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `updateOn` is `'blur'`.

- [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#note-on-performance)
- [Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n5cae8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: that's it! much appreciated.